# Debugging a callback in TensorFlow with pdb in eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, pdb

How properly debug a callback in TensoFlow with [pdb in eager](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2#use_tfconfigexperimental_run_functions_eagerly_when_debugging) execution mode? The following scenario shows the error. The callback is a metric function of this form:

```
def my_custom_metric_in_top_k(k):
    def metric_in_top_k(labels,predictions,features):
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        ...
    return metric_in_top_k
```

While inside pdb console, I create a session with `sess=tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()`, then I can get values of the label tensor via `labels.eval()`. However, when I run `predictions.eval()` I get the following error

> *** tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:
> Error while reading resource variable group_score/dense_2/bias from
> Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was
> uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/group_score/batch_normalization_2/gamma/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.

What causes the error and how to make `predictions.eval()` work? Also, any advice on debugging callbacks in Tensorflow?

Edit:
I suspect that the issue is that there are two different sessions: the interactive one and the session that was used to read the model. However, I read the models by providing a directory with training check points while creating [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/Estimator) instance, and the calling `evaluate` on the estimator. It seems to me that the session was created somewhere within estimator.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has a similar issue, the problem was that TF was turning off the eager execution mode. The way to check is via the `tf.execusing_eagerly()` call.